# repeat each element of vector by number specified in a numeric vector

Tags: r, repeat

```
d <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
n <- c(1, 2, 5)
```

I would like to produce output:

```
res <- c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c')
```

Is there a function which can use `d` and `n` to produce such a result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `rep()`:

```
rep(d, n)

[1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c"
```